# Lunch flutter app on the real device with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

I have a question for you. I have a old MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and for this reason I can’t run the iOS app because I can't update the system and Xcode to the latest version.
I wanted to ask you if I can bypass this problem by running the application directly on my iPhone 13 pro using Android studio.

Thank you !